# How to bind mouseover with click event in a more responsive way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following code:

```
    jQuery("ul.nav-200 li").hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).click();
    }).click(function() {

    });
```

to make hover event mimic the behavior of click event in the slider I have got at:

```
https://www.trimenergy.com.au/
```

The html of the slider where these two events need to be 'bound' is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-200 clearfix">
  <li class="active"> 
   <span><h1 class="slidetitle">New LED Downlight</h1><span class="slidedescription">Introducing our new TE101 LED downlight kit</span></span></li><li class=""> 
   <span><h1 class="slidetitle">Sensor Lighting</h1>
   <span class="slidedescription">Sensor &amp; LED lighting for increased efficiency</span></span></li>
 <li class=""> 
  <span><h1 class="slidetitle">Motion Sensors</h1>
  <span class="slidedescription">Motion &amp; presence sensors for all applications</span></span></li>
 <li class="">
  <span><h1 class="slidetitle">$9.95 Flat Rate</h1>
  <span class="slidedescription">We charge a flat $9.95 for shipping Australiawide</span></span></li>
 <li class=""> <span><h1 class="slidetitle">Increase Efficiency</h1><span class="slidedescription">Contact us to find out how you can save on your electricity bills!</span></span>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

At the moment, although the slider is behaving the way I want it to behave but it is not as responsive as I would like it to be (if you hover your mouse over it time and again it stops responding to the mouseover event) . I do not want to alter the javascript that came with core plugin and am looking for an alternative like I am employing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the actual plugin itself. You could try:

```
$("ul.nav-200 li").mouseenter(function()
{
$(this).click();
});
```

Or clicking twice to see if it would take

Comment: Tried mouseenter , still getting similar 'lag' in response after hovering mouse a few times.